# Doing git pull changes the permission of untracked files

Tags: git-lfs

I've been having a problem where all files that I don't want to be tracked by git keep changing permission from 644 to 444 whenever I do git pull (I'm currently using CentOS 7). I'm using git-lfs with the .gitattributes contains:

```
[!.]* filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text lockable
```

I've also set the following in the .git/config

```
[core]
filemode = false
autocrlf = true
```

I've been using git-lfs to tracked all type of files that being pushed to the remote server but there are files that I wished stayed and can be edited locally. Its a hassle to change the permission everytime I am pulling the changes from remote.

Answer (score 0):

If those files are "lockable", that means you chan try and unlock them, using [`git lfs unlock`](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-unlock.1.ronn).

That would change their locked state (444) to one which can be modified (unlocked, 644).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but as far as I know, git lfs unlock can only unlock files that have been committed. It seems like git-lfs track all files in the local repo because I can lock files that haven't been pushed to remote server

Comment: @MeorIzzat I thought those files were tracked already.